# Merging text files in .bat with line break between files

Tags: csv, batch-file

I'm trying to create a .bat file to run on Windows 10.
Basically I have multiple .csv files in a folder.

FileA.csv

```
abc,abc
def,def
```

FileB.csv

```
ghi,ghi
jkl,jkl
```

I want the files to be merged to FileC.csv formatted like this.

```
abc,abc
def,def
ghi,ghi
jkl,jkl
```

If I use:

```
copy /b *.csv FileC.csv
```

I get this output in FileC.csv:

```
abc,abc
def,defghi,ghi
jkl,jkl
```

I need to add a line break between merged files but can't figure out how.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
type A.csv >> C.csv
echo. >> C.csv
type B.csv >> C.csv
```

1. Type will show the contents of a file
2. `>>C.csv` will append the output to an existig file
3. `echo.` will print an empty line

**UPD**

```
FOR %f IN (*.csv) DO type %f >> ..\newfile.csv & echo. >> ..\newfile.csv
```

this will merge all `.csv` files in new `.csv` file in parent folder (if that new file will be same folder, after create first iteration, for also merge that file too)

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I wanted.  Is there a way to do every *.csv file in a folder or do I have to explicitly list each file I want merged?

Comment: You're welcome. updated answer. If my answer is what you wanted, upvote and accept answer.

Comment: OK this is working great except there is a line break the end of the created file.  How do I remove that?

Answer (score 0):

In a cmd window this will insert breaks and remove empty lines:

```
(for /f "delims=" %A in ('Type FileA.csv^&Echo:^&Type FileB.csv') Do @Echo %A)>FileC.csv
```

In a batch

```
@Echo off
( for /f "delims=" %%A in (
    'Type fileA.csv^&Echo:^&Type FileB.csv'
  ) Do @Echo:%%A
) > FileC.csv
```

Comment: I tried that and it still leaves me a blank line at the end of the created file

Answer (score 0):

### If a space before each line break is acceptable

```
@echo off
rem Concatenate input text files, inserting a line break between each file

set inpattern=*.csv
set outfile=all.csv
set count=0

rem Delete any existing output file
del /q %outfile%
rem Count the number of input files
for %%f in (%inpattern%) do (call :count "%%f")
rem Concatenate the input files
for %%f in (%inpattern%) do (call :concat "%%f")
goto :EOF
rem End of main routine

rem Subroutines

:count
rem Increment the input file counter
set /a count+=1
goto :EOF

:concat
rem Append this input file to the output file
type %1 >> %outfile%
rem If this is not the last input file, then append a line break to the output file
if %count% gtr 1 echo.>> %outfile%
rem Decrement the input file counter
set /a count-=1
goto :EOF
```

About this script:

- The `echo.` command inserts a space (`\x20` byte) followed by a Windows-style two-byte line break: a carriage return (Cr, `\x0D`) followed by a line feed (Lf, `\x0A`).
- The lack of a space in the script between `echo.` and `>>` is deliberate. If there is a space between `echo.` and `>>`, then the `echo.` "honors" that space, and the output contains two spaces before the line break.

The space before the line break annoys me, but I can live with it.

### Otherwise

If you cannot live with a space before the line break, or you need a Unix-style line break (or some other type of line break):

1. Create a text file, `linebreak.txt`, that contains only the line break.
2. Use the following slightly modified script, which appends the `linebreak.txt` file between the input files, instead of using the `echo.` command.

```
@echo off
rem Concatenate input text files, inserting a line break between each file

set inpattern=*.csv
set outfile=all.csv
set linebreak=linebreak.txt
set count=0

rem Delete any existing output file
del /q %outfile%
rem Count the number of input files
for %%f in (%inpattern%) do (call :count "%%f")
rem Concatenate the input files
for %%f in (%inpattern%) do (call :concat "%%f")
goto :EOF
rem End of main routine

rem Subroutines

:count
rem Increment the input file counter
set /a count+=1
goto :EOF

:concat
rem Append this input file to the output file
type %1 >> %outfile%
rem If this is not the last input file, then append a line break to the output file
if %count% gtr 1 type %linebreak% >> %outfile%
rem Decrement the input file counter
set /a count-=1
goto :EOF
```

Comment: I'm using this to concatenate multi-megabyte text files. The `type` command is very slow. I'll likely look for, or develop, a faster solution (perhaps in Python or PowerShell).

Comment: I regret using `type` in this answer. It works, but I wish I'd held off, and—given that I've already taken the step of having a separate file containing the line break—developed an answer that manufactures a single `copy` command, like this:

`copy a.csv + linebreak.txt + b.csv + linebreak.txt + c.csv all.csv`

I suspect this would be more performant (run faster).

Maybe later I'll submit a new answer using `copy`.

Comment: I forgot to add a `/b` switch to the `copy` command in my previous comment (to avoid a substitution character, `\x1A`, at the end of the output file).